# Will ASUS GeForce DUAL-GTX1060-O6G 6 GB run 2 4k monitors for development?

Tags: graphics-cards, multiple-monitors, 4k

I have an older PC - (I7/3770K @ 3.5GHz, 32Gb DDR3) with an ASUS GeForce DUAL-GTX1060-O6G 6 GB card. I currently have 2 22" IIyama 1680x1050 monitors.

I'd like to upgrade my monitors to 2 x 32" 4k monitors.

My usage is 99% non-gaming - mostly software development, Word/Excel, and browsing. Gaming tends to be older games - Tomb Raider, Elite Dangerous.

My question is will my pc + card run these monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to [manufacturer specifications](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Graphics-Cards/Dual/DUAL-GTX1060-O6G/techspec/). Yes